# Function descriptors in Microsoft Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

I have ben using microsoft visual studio for some time, and just discovered that you can give parameter descriptions for the functions. But I would also like to be able to use something like pre and post descriptions for the functions, is that possible?

For info;

- I'm using Microsoft visual studio (as mentioned)
- Using C++, but would be nice if it would also work for other programming languages

```
/**
* This the version of quicksort that actually performs partitioning, recursive calls, etc.
*
* @param ar = pointer til arrayet
* @param start = sted man skal starte med at sorte
* @param end = stedet sorting skal slutte
* 
* @pre gets an unsorted array
* 
*/
template<typename T>
void quicksort(T* ar, int start, int end)
{
    // if (base case reached) return;  // Base case: No sorting necessary 

    // select pivot index and position pivot;
    // partition ar[start; end];

    // Assume: Pivot is at index k after partitioning 
    // quicksort(ar, start, k - 1);
    // quicksort(ar, k + 1, end);
}
```

[How it looks with parameter descriptions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvxdU.png)

I have tried searching on google, and I can see something with doxygen and xml documentation, but I'm not sure how to get it to work.

Comment: Where should the pre and post descriptions appear compared to the summary? Or should the text between the respective tags just appear anywhere at all in the info popup?

Comment: I have made @YujianYao-MSFT 's answear the anwser for the post, even tho when i use the <param i get warning stating that XML won't let me use "<", but if i just use the syntax the XML makes automatix when using /// it works as you stated. Thanks for the help

Comment: @Sebastian well I got an answer from Yuhian Xao, to answer you, I would like them to just be somewhere, preferably with pre first and post after that. so that it would bething like
**Pre**  yaba yaba yaba
**Post** yaba yaba yaba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XML document automatically generated after typing "///" is supported in Visual Studio 2019 16.6 and later versions. Examples are as follows:

I entered "output a character" in `<summary></summary>`, so "output a character" appears in the function description below.

[image]